# Map is not function in Angular RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm just trying to use the map function but it throws an error.Inside the results.map(results => etc) it says that 'Symbol Map cannot be properly resolved, probably it is located in inaccessible module'

,[image]

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { take, map,filter, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
etc

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  public project: IProject;

  constructor(

    private appSer: AppService) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {

    this.appSer.project$
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        map(results =>
          results.map(result => ({
            ...result,
            square: result.square * 5000

          })))
      )
      .subscribe(
        (result: IProject) => {
          console.log(result);

        },
        (error: any) => {
          console.error(error);
        },

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the data typeof `results`?

Comment: Its a object of IProject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, the type of *results* is an object remove the extra map operator.

```
  .pipe(
    map(result => ({
      ...result,
      square: result.square * 5000
    }))
  )
```

If *result* was an array then you would need the extra `map` operator.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the second map, just do like so:

```
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        map(results => ({
            ...result,
            square: result.square * 5000
        }))
      )
```

(just make sure to match the brackets)

Comment: @HJ1990 Added the object braces, try that